# Why does HEAD in my worktree point to the top commit in master?

Tags: git, git-worktree

I created a worktree using `git worktree add` and it was working as expected for a few days. Today, I wanted to check out some code at the previous revision, so I temporarily detached `HEAD`:

```
git checkout head^
```

After I found what I needed, I tried to go back to the tip of my worktree branch:

```
git checkout <branchname>
```

But now, `HEAD` is pointing to the top commit in my local `master` branch. For example:

```
git show head
```

shows the most recent commit in `master`.

Any ideas why this happened or how to fix it?

---

**EDIT**

I'm also seeing some weird, inconsistent behavior. For example, this:

```
> git reset --hard
HEAD is now at 4f1666467017
> git rev-parse head
e4fab17872cce2f6f37f5b596c7ed2739b135f3f
```

Comment: Note that `head` and `HEAD` are two different things

Comment: Assuming that everywhere you have `head` you mean `HEAD`. It seems that `<branchname>` and `master` both point to the same commit.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR

Don't spell it `head` (lowercase).  Spell it `HEAD` (all uppercase).  *Git* is case-sensitive, even where typical Windows and macOS file systems are not.

(If typing that many uppercase letters is an issue, use `@`, which is a one-letter synonym for `HEAD`.  This works everywhere in Git versions 2.0 and up, and almost everywhere even in the ancient versions of Git still found on some CentOS systems.)

#### Longer

The weirdness here is related to the fact that each work-tree has its own private `HEAD` file.  Different operations may find different `HEAD` files by case-folding: there's a `.git/worktrees/worktree/HEAD` file for the added work-tree, and a `.git/HEAD` file for the main work-tree.  When operation *A* picks `.git/HEAD` to match `head` while operation *B* picks `.git/worktrees/worktree/HEAD`, you see exactly this behavior.  Using all-capitals `HEAD` makes Git do the right thing.

In particular, `git reset --hard` internally uses `HEAD` in all capitals, which will refer to the per-work-tree `HEAD`, while `git rev-parse head` uses lowercase `head`, which will refer to the `.git/HEAD` file.

#### Attached vs detached HEAD

You can check out any historical commit by its raw hash ID:

```
git checkout a123456
```

(or in modern Git since 2.23, `git switch --detach hash`: note the requirement that you add `--detach`, which helps avoid accidents.)

The result is what Git calls a *detached HEAD*.  Normally the special name `HEAD` (in all capital letters) is *attached*, to a branch name:

```
...--A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD)
         \
          E--F--G   <-- branch
```

(the uppercase letters here stand in for the actual commit hash IDs).  By being attached like this, `HEAD` means `master` which means commit `D`.  So your current commit is now whatever commit `D`'s real hash ID is.  If you run:

```
git checkout branch
```

you get:

```
...--A--B--C--D   <-- master
         \
          E--F--G   <-- branch (HEAD)
```

which means your current *branch* is `branch` and your current *commit* is now `G`.

When you pick a commit by hash ID, though—let's say commit `E`—you make `HEAD` point directly to that commit:

```
...--A--B--C--D   <-- master
         \
          E   <-- HEAD
           \
            F--G   <-- branch
```

This is what Git calls "detached HEAD"; your current commit is commit `E`.

Now, you didn't use a raw hash ID.  Instead, you typed in `head^`.  But there are lots of ways to name commits.  The raw hash ID is the lowest-level way: a hash ID always works and always means *that one specific commit*, but you can also have Git find the *parent* of some commit.  That's what `HEAD^` means: select the parent of the current commit.  Suppose the current commit is `G` because you're on `branch`; then `HEAD^` names commit `F`, and after:

```
git checkout HEAD^
```

you will have:

```
...--A--B--C--D   <-- master
         \
          E--F   <-- HEAD
              \
               G   <-- branch
```

The lowercase version `head` typically works on Windows and macOS, but not on Linux.  This is a side effect of the fact that Git sometimes stores these things in files (`.git/HEAD`, and `.git/refs/heads/master`, for instance).  Using `head` instead of `HEAD`, Git might try to open `.git/refs/heads/head`, which doesn't exist, but when Git tries to open `.git/head`, it gets `.git/HEAD`, which *does* exist.  So *on these machines*, `git checkout head^` means the same thing as `git checkout HEAD^`: find the current commit, step back to its first parent, and check out *that* commit.

To re-attach your `HEAD` to some branch, use `git checkout branch-name`.

If you're not on Windows or macOS (or even if you are), note that you can *also* create a *branch or tag* named `head`.  If you do, things get a bit squirrelly, especially on Windows and MacOS, as there are now *two* ways to resolve `head`: as the branch or tag, and as `.git/HEAD`.  It's best to just not do this.  If you do it by mistake, simply delete the lowercase version (`git branch -d head` for instance).

Comment: +1
I also encountered this issue while on Windows and `head` will use the main HEAD while `HEAD` uses the actual worktree HEAD.